# Python code in Django not recompiling in daemon mode with Apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am running a Django application using Apache2 with mod_wsgi in daemon mode:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess my_app_process
WSGIScriptAlias /my_app /var/www/my_app/wsgi.py process-group=my_app_process
WSGIScriptReloading On
```

Whenever I make changes to my Python code on server (I know this is highly discouraged, but I'm only using it for debugging) I keep having trouble with recompiling the code, but only in subdirectories.

Python files in the root directory of the application (i.e. settings.py) get recompiled nicely, but not the ones located in subdirectories (i.e. views.py of some app).

The application directory is owned by the www-data user and the user has sufficient privileges (tested with 777).

Restarting the Apache or touching the wsgi file only results in recompiling of the Python files in root directory of the application.

**EDIT:**

I also tried adding the WSGIProcessGroup directive with no effect:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess my_app_process processes=2 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup my_app_process
WSGIScriptAlias /my_app /var/www/my_app/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptReloading On
```

Also, using the code provided [here](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html) I have concluded I am, in fact, running in daemon mode.

**EDIT #2**

Added Apache log from restart:

```
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.309060 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.309186 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.309876 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28375:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28375): Starting process 'my_app' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.310193 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28375:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28375): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.310246 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28376:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28376): Starting process 'my_app_2' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.310531 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28377:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28377): Starting process 'my_app_3' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.310607 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28376:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28376): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.310855 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28377:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28377): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.311029 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.311057 2017] [mpm_event:info] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] AH00490: Server built: Sep 15 2016 20:44:43
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.311071 2017] [core:notice] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.311379 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28379:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28379): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.311507 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28378:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28378): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.324667 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28377:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28377): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.324671 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28376:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28376): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.324843 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28377:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28377): Adding '/var/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.324864 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28376:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28376): Adding '/var/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.324988 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28378:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28378): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.329741 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28379:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28379): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.335879 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28375:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28375): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:06.336042 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28375:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28375): Adding '/var/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Fri Jan 06 12:03:13.598083 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28375:tid 139790204262144] [remote 10.6.6.58:512] mod_wsgi (pid=28375, process='my_app', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/my_app/wsgi.py'.
```

Added Apache log from touching the WSGI script:

```
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.348075 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Shutdown requested 'my_app'.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.348217 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Stopping process 'my_app'.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.348237 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.348244 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.348954 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Terminating Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.469333 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:28.469366 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28835:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Exiting process 'my_app'.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.129042 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Process 'my_app' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.129094 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Process 'my_app' terminated normally, exit code 0
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.129099 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28372:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28835): Process 'my_app' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.129764 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28917:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28917): Starting process 'my_app' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.130173 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28917:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28917): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.144492 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28917:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28917): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.144687 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28917:tid 139790316758912] mod_wsgi (pid=28917): Adding '/var/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Fri Jan 06 12:12:29.147279 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28917:tid 139790204262144] [remote 10.6.6.58:512] mod_wsgi (pid=28917, process='my_app', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/my_app/wsgi.py'.
```

Comment: Can you actually clarify what you mean by 'recompiling' so we know we are talking about the same thing. One doesn't usually talk about Python code being recompiled. Are you only talking about processes being restarted and when that happens they load the latest Python code? Or are you actually looking to see if newer ``.pyc`` files are being generated from ``.py`` files? Have you tried removing all the ``.pyc`` files?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the actual .pyc files, which are not regenerated whenever I change the .py files. The .pyc files are not regenerated even after removing the old ones. Doing so doesn't even break the application as, instead it runs smoothly without the .pyc files. It seems as if the compiled version of the older code is still cached somewhere.

Comment: Usually under Apache/mod_wsgi the ``.pyc`` files will not be regenerated because the user Apache runs your code as will not have write access to directories/files anyway. This is fine as they are usually long lived processes so you get little from having them as don't often load code anyway.

Comment: Things can be screwed up where you copy files into place from another system. If the timestamps are updated such that .pyc files are newer than .py files, the older code in .pyc file will always be used as has newer timestamp.

Comment: In short, you don't need the .pyc files anyway, as Python will just read the .py file and compile it into byte code and cache it in process, for the life of the process. It is not like PHP where code is effectively thrown away after each request. Because cached in process, multi process configurations can see old code still being used in some processes if making live edits and you aren't forcing code reloading properly.

Comment: OK, but restarting the process should then reload and recompile the code (after removing the .pyc files). However, Python still seems to be running using the older version of the code (the changes I make in .py files do not manifest in the application). I haven't copied anything - the code comes straight from a git repository.

Comment: If you stop and start Apache, or even just do a reload/restart, if the only code available is the original Python code files, there is no way it can be using old versions. I would suggest you check your filesystems to see if you have multiple copies of code and are using the wrong one. Wouldn't be the first time seen someone do that.

Comment: I know it certainly smells that way, but I have repeatedly checked whether I'm running the correct code (I even tried removing all other applications from the filesystem). I have also tried removing the application code: if I mess up the settings.py file, application dies (which means I'm modifying the correct instance). However, if I change or remove any Python files in any of the subdirectories of the application, the applications runs fine (after restarting the Apache).

Comment: Have you do a complete restart of your system to make sure there isn't some other Apache instance with processes still running that may be conflicting.

Comment: Just tried that with no success, application is still working with broken .py files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing the `WSGIProcessGroup` directive:

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#delegation-to-daemon-process

> To make use of daemon mode for WSGI applications hosted within a
>   specific site, the WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup directives
>   would need to be defined. For example, to setup a daemon process group
>   containing two multithreaded process one could use: WSGIDaemonProcess
>   example.com processes=2 threads=15 WSGIProcessGroup example.com

This being said, unless the issues you need to debug are specific to your deployment configuration, you'd be better working locally with the [builtin dev server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver)

Comment: Tried adding the directive with no effect (see the edit).

Comment: Duh... my mod_wsgi fu might not be up to date but that _should_ have worked.

Comment: Have you tried setting your log level to info and watching your logs (both your vhost logs and the main apache logs) ?

Comment: Added the Apache logs. I do have multiple applications running under one vhost, but this shouldn't be an issue according to the log as each application has its own process.

Answer (score 0):

It would be by chance that you are seeing changes due to wrongly running in embedded mode, which probably means new process gets request if using prefork MPM.

In addition to properly setting up embedded mode, which is is preferred, read the documentation about source code reloading at:

- [Source Code Reloading in mod_wsgi](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html)

Comment: All things indicate I'm running correctly in daemon mode (tried with the WSGI script from the docs). I also used the WSGI script from here http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html to determine I'm likely running on worker MPM. The Apache binary didn't provide the MPM information. I will read further about configuring the embedded mode though.

Comment: You _dont_ want to run in embedded mode, definitely